# How Internet Explorer(IE11)Creates low Integrity child process without CreateProcess Call

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi, windbg

I want to know how Internet Explorer creates low integrity un-trusted sandboxed child processes without calling CreateProcess API.

Here what I tried:

Opened the executable (iexplore.exe) in Windbg. At the time of initial BP hit i set a break point at Kernel32!CreateProcessA. Then i just let the main IE process run. I could see it's created sandboxed child processes (low integrity child iexplore.exe) in process explorer / process hacker utility, but it does not touch the CreateProcess break point.

[image]

I wanna know how IE does that.

Comment: Maybe use NtCreateProcess ?

Comment: It looks like they're using [`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @AndrewLambert you are right..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Kernel32!CreateProcessA` is at the top of the chain and is a wrapper to calls further down the chain

the final call that crosses the `usermode kernelmode border is ntdll!NtCreateProcessEx` in api form  and hacks can be used to burrow deeper and cross the border by setting up the stack and `calling sysenter directly`

try setting breakpoints in `kernel32!CreateProcessW` / `kernel32!CreateProcessInternal` `Advapi32!CreateProcessAsUser` / `ntdll!ntCreateProcessEx` etc

Comment: Well said. I'd also add that if you actually want to debug into the child process, you should opt for using: `.childdbg 1; sxe cpr` in windbg.

Comment: well how can i get the PID of child process from the handle returned by kernel32!CreateProcessInternal()  using windbg / or any other debugger from parent process(debugger attached to parent process only)..??

Comment: how did you retrieve the handle

Comment: Look at [`GetProcessId()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683215.aspx), or just read the `dwProcessId` field of the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` struct that `CreateProcess/AsUser()` outputs.